# Android bumping/file sharing technology

Tags: android

There are a number of applications on the market that allow Android phones to exchange files or some other information. Those applications usually rely on two Android devices being in close proximity and detecting each other's presence. I do not think that they use bluetooth communication to send signal to each other since bluetooth can be off and it would take some time to activate it so bumping would take longer than it does in those applications. Thus those apps have to use some other sensors that most of android phones are equipped with.

Do you have any idea of what those sensors are and how the phones become aware of each other's presence?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this tech is based on two inputs - accelerator and physical location (GPS). The timing of the accelerator signals from both phones needs to match very precisely, and the respective locations must be close enough. The resolution is limited by physical precision of the clock and the GPS, but I guess it's precise enough on available devices to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't presume to speak for all such applications but Bump uses your location and the time you initiate the bump to create a match through its centralized server. You can check out the little bit of details available at their FAQ http://bu.mp/faq#android.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above answers, using NFC is the more hip thing to do.

- [A video that shows how to use NFC in Android.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49L7z3rxz4Q&noredirect=1)
- Take a look at the [NFC tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/index.html)